# Cannot resolve V3CommentListResponse class/symbol, YouTube Data API Java sample issue

Tags: java, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

In this page of `YouTube Data API` [Java Samples](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/comments/list)
the Java code, I can't find:

```
import com.google.api.services.youtube.model.V3CommentListResponse;
import com.google.api.services.youtube.model.V3CommentThreadListResponse;
```

I tried to download this jar file but can't resolve `V3CommentListResponse`, how to use this class?

Answer (score 8):

They probably changed the name of the class since writing those samples. What you probably need is [CommentListResponse](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/youtube/v3/java/latest/com/google/api/services/youtube/model/CommentListResponse.html).

The jar file can be downloaded from here: https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/download/youtube/v3/java

Comment: Thank you very much. Alin, I have downloaded this jar file. But I still can't find import com.google.api.services.samples.youtube.cmdline.Auth; I have tried to find this on http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/g/Catalogg.htm, but no result. do you know how to address it.

Comment: That class is part of the API code samples. See here https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/master/java/src/main/java/com/google/api/services/samples/youtube/cmdline/Auth.java. You can either clone that Gihub repository, or download the zip archive from the [projects page](https://github.com/youtube/api-samples). Java2s is not really the definitive place to look for resources and source code.

Comment: I am sorry, but I cannot understand much from the code that is split across so many small comments. Please try to create a new question for this other problem that you have. Also, please format the code properly so that it is easier to understand.

Comment: Hi Alin, I have formatted this problem. You can refer to on this website http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30385433/insufficient-permission-when-run-youtube-retriving-comments   I am green hand, thank you for your patience.

Comment: I have had the same problem. Thank you @Alin Pandichi!