# Insufficient Permission (403) for CommentThreads: list YouTube API Method with read-only scope

Tags: youtube-api, google-oauth, youtube-data-api

We're using a [CommentThreads: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/commentThreads/list) YouTube API Method to get all comments associated with a YouTube Channel, and for at least half a year it was working fine with YouTube v3 Data API *www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly* scope. The scope is read-only, as we only need to get comments, not write anything. Since a few weeks ago it's not possible to do that with a read-only scope (it returns 403 "Insufficient Permission" error), a full scope *www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl* is needed to list comments.

The token is obtained via Google OAuth2 process.

The read-only scope is an [official scope for the API](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/googlescopes#youtubev3), and I couldn't locate any limitations on using it in the docs for list methods, and there seems to be no announced changes to the API (as it stopped working only recently). Did anyone else experience similar problems?

Comment: If you check the link that you provide [CommentThreads: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/commentThreads/list), you will notice that in the given example using either JAVA, PHP or PYTHON, it uses the scope `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl`. So it seems that this method required this scope to work.

Comment: Same issue as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30385433/insufficient-permission-when-run-youtube-retriving-comments

Answer (score -1):

If your project doesn't require using only Google OAuth2.

You could try to access CommentThreads:list API by using API Key.

[Obtaining authorization credentials](https://developers.google.com/youtube/registering_an_application)

The only downside is that you won't be able to retrieve your own comments, other than that it works like a charm.